# Passing Self in a static function

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I am using migrating from Objective-C with MagicalRecord to Swift with CoreStack (being used as the Core Data framework). And the CoreStack has the following API to fetch a record, something like the following:

```
CoreStore.fetchOne(From<NSManagedObject>, Where("id == '123'))
```

I have a base class for my NSManagedObject's - Record, and would like to have a static function that returns a record (of any subclass) with ID:

```
class Record : NSManagedObject {

   static public func find(id: String) -> Self {
      CoreStore.fetchOne(From<Self>, Where("id = '\(id)'"))
   }

}

class Person: Record {

   var id: String?

}
```

Use:

```
Person.find(id: '123')
```

But I cannot find a way to pass 'Self' class to this function. Mostly what I get is an error: Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function

I tried to use a global function (not a method), so there is less restrictions:

```
public func findRecord<T: Record>(id: String) -> T {
    return CoreStore.fetchOne(From<T>, Where("id = '\(id)'"))
}
```

That is used in the `Record` class like this:

```
static public func find(id: String) -> Self {
    find<Self>(Where("id = '\(id)'"))
}
```

And all to no avail. I would appreciate any ideas or pointers!

**Updated:**

```
class Record : NSManagedObject
```

- also added example for global function
- here is the link to [sample project](https://github.com/rzolin/Generics)

Comment: try using your class name `Record` instead of `Self`, and replace `class Record {` with  `class Record : NSManagedObject {` as your method is waiting a  `NSManagedObject` as i can see, let me know if works

Comment: My bad, the `Record` is inherited from `NSManagedObject`. But the problem is still there: cannot pass `Self` or `type(of: self)` to the generic function from static method

Comment: And if I understand you correctly: if I use `Record` while passing to `CoreStore.fetchOne<Record>()` it will not know which class to instantiate/find

Comment: You're using a static function, your class don't need be instantiated to use that function, in fact static functions are called `class function`that is why you don´t need any instance, so try what I put in my previous comment must work, I think

Comment: Calling `CoreStore.fetchOne<Record>(From<Record>, Where(clause))` from that static function (of the class Record) gives the same error: `Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function`. I hope I implemented your approach correctly

Comment: this is a real proyect or test one? can you post an example code of this in github to review it?

Comment: It is a real project. I can try to compile a simple project for us to go through. Give me a minute or 5 :) It doesn't actually matter whether it's Core Data or anything else - just the general approach to converting the call from base class (in static function) to a generic function

Comment: Updated the post with the link to the sample project at the bottom

Comment: removing `<Record>` from this line `return Generic.fetch<Record>()` in your example project error go away can you check that?

Comment: Hey Reinier, your approach worked - remove all brackets when calling the function:  `CoreStore.fetchOne(From(), Where("id = '\(id)'"))`. It looks like the compiler infers the types. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use self in a static function because self refers to an instance where static functions / properties refer to the class itself.

Consider the line Person.find(id: '123'). Is 123 a property that is exactly the same on every Person object or does each Person have a different id? Currently id is the a property of the instance. Every Person object can have a different id. If it was a class property then every single instance would have the same id.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? As I understand there are two types of `self`: Class (Self) and object (self). So why cannot I pass the class where the static function resides? At the moment of the call there is no instance/object that I am passing - just the type. And I want to pass the type. Am I missing something?

Comment: Let's try to break it down with the example. I want to convert the call:
`Person.find(id: '123')`
to
`CoreStore.fetchOne<Person>()`
within the static function in the base class `Record`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Reinier Melian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6190582/reinier-melian), the answer is rather simple:

```
class Record : NSManagedObject {

   static public func find(id: String) -> Self {
      CoreStore.fetchOne(From(), Where("id = '\(id)'"))
   }

}

class Person: Record {

   var id: String?

}
```

Somewhere in the CoreStore:

```
public static func fetchOne<T>(_ from: From<T>, _ fetchClauses: FetchClause...) -> T? {

     return self.defaultStack.fetchOne(from, fetchClauses)
}
```

**The solution:**

Just remove the brackets <> and let the compiler infer the type.